# mysql group return all row

Tags: mysql, group-by

i have a question here..

lets say i have this table...

```
waktu               |   tglTransaksiJual   | nominal   | ongkir    | STATUS    | idUser
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2013-02-01 00:00:00 | 2013-01-29 15:00:00  | 10000     | 10000     | APPROVED  | 1
0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2013-02-02 15:00:00  | 20000     | 0         | DONE      | 2
0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2013-02-02 15:00:00  | 10000     | 5000      | DONE      | 2
2013-02-03 00:00:00 | 2013-02-01 15:00:00  | 20000     | 0         | APPROVED  | 3
```

AND i use this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(date(IF(waktu = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', tglTransaksiJual, waktu))) AS thedate, SUM( nominal+ongkir ) AS total
        FROM transaksijual
        WHERE IF(waktu = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', tglTransaksiJual, waktu) BETWEEN '2013-02-01' AND '2013-02-05' AND status LIKE 'DONE%' AND idUser LIKE '2%'    
        GROUP BY thedate
        ORDER BY thedate ASC
```

But the result i have is

```
thedate    | total
-------------------
2013-02-01 | 30000
```

And that i want is like this

```
thedate    | total
------------------
2013-02-01 | 0
2013-02-02 | 35000
2013-02-03 | 0
```

How can i do that?? is that possible??
so the conclusion is.. when there's no data i want to get 0 values and get the row...

Comment: Your `WHERE` conditions specify `DONE` and `idUSer = 2`, but these do not match any of the other date columns.  Is this on purpose or what?

Comment: Yes... my question how to still return a row with 0values when no condition match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `WHERE` condition and update the `SUM` column to only sum if the condition is met:

```
SUM(IF(status = 'DONE' AND idUser = '2', nominal + ongkir, 0))
```

Comment: @user2070749 please edit your comment and make it not all caps (or just delete it; you're welcome).  Don't forget to upvote good answers too

Comment: hey, may i ask you one more question?? how to use it on count(*), i mean if i change the sum to count() are its just the same?

Comment: @user2070749 you should be able to use it the same.  Don't use `COUNT(*)`, just use something like `COUNT(IF(..., 1, 0))`